# Consumer producer multithreading issue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm having issues implementing the following scheme in multithreading :

```
class OneThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, eval_queue, result_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.eval_queue = eval_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        while work_left:
            while (len(self.eval_queue.values()) < some_const or \
                  len(self.result_queue.values()) > 0):
                  # wait for eval queue to be full and result_queue
                  # to be empty

            # fill result_queue while emptying eval_queue


class ManyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, eval_queue, result_queue, thread_id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.eval_queue = eval_queue

    def run(self):
        while len(self.eval_queue.values()) < some_const and \
                len(self.result_queue.values()) == 0:
                # wait for eval_queue to not be full and
                # for result queue to be empty

        # fill eval_queue
        # wait until result_queue is full

        # use result_queue while emptying it

eval_queue = {}
result_queue = {}
evaluator = OneThread(eval_queue, result_queue)
evaluator.start()
for i in range(some_range):
    eval_queue.clear()
    result_queue.clear()
    for j in range(some_range):
        threads.append(ManyThread(eval_queue, result_queue))
        threads[-1].start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
evaluator.join()
```

I already tried using Conditions, but it gets messy in the code as well as 
in my brain. The main goal is to have on one thread an evaluator that checks whether the eval_queue is full and the result_queue is empty. When it is, the evaluator thread does some operation on the eval_queue and fills the result_queue with the results while emptying the eval_queue. The corresponding threads are waiting until the result_queue is filled in order to use it while emptying it and also wait until the result_queue is empty to start filling it up again.

I can't seem to find a better way of doing this kind of scheme without it being too painful ! Any idea ? (can't use multiprocessing because I need shared memory and my computation isn't totally bound by the CPU so I would gain quite a lot by doing it) !

Thanks!

Comment: Without looking deep into the code, have you tried using a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) instead of plain dictionaries? Dictionary access is not necessarily atomic and may cause all sorts of weird artifacts when being accessed/modified from different threads.

Comment: Nop I haven't, perhaps it's the key ! I will try it out and see how it does, but I'm still not too sure about how to do the Conditions properly, so the results might not be accurate because of it !